# Extend a controller from controller in another module?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I have this module called 'olo' which handles all our online ordering stuff.

Now I have made a new module called 'olosec' because I wish make a different version with a slight changed flow, and some other changes in some of the controllers.

Is it possible for me to extend a controller in 'olosec' with a controller in 'olo'?

As of now I have tried

```
class Olosec_CartController extends Olo_CartController
```

Which throws an error like

```
Warning: include_once(Olo/CartController.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146 Warning:
include_once(): Failed opening 'Olo/CartController.php' for inclusion.
bla bla bla (include path) bla bla bla
```

My directory structure is something like this (thanks `tree \F \A` and [EditPlus++](http://www.editplus.com))

```
+---application
|   +---views
|   |   +---scripts
|   |   +---layouts
|   |   |   +---default
|   |   |   +---admin
|   |   +---languages
|   |   +---helpers
|   +---modules
|   |   +---admin
|   |   +---mobile
|   |   +---olo
|   |   |   +---controllers
|   |       |       IndexController.php
|   |       |       MenuController.php
|   |       |       CartController.php
|   |       |       OrderlistController.php
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   +---models
|   |   |   \---views
|   |   |       +---helpers
|   |   |       \---scripts
|   |   |           +---index
|   |   |           +---menu
|   |   |           +---cart
|   |   |           \---orderlist
|   |   \---olosec
|   |       +---controllers
|   |       |       IndexController.php
|   |       |       MenuController.php
|   |       |       CartController.php
|   |       |       OrderlistController.php
|   |       |
|   |       +---models
|   |       \---views
|   |           +---helpers
|   |           \---scripts
|   |               +---index
|   |               +---menu
|   |               +---cart
|   |               \---orderlist
|   +---models
|   +---controllers
|   \---configs
+---library
+---public
|   +---cli
|   \---default
+---tests
\---data
```

**Update**

I have used this "nasty" hack which works

```
require_once( APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/olo/controllers/CartController.php');
```

**Update @ Rakesh**

I have this in my bootstrap..

```
function _initAutoloader() {
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    return $autoloader;
}
```

In my application.ini

```
autoloadernamespaces.0 = "Zend"
autoloadernamespaces.1 = "My"
autoloadernamespaces.2 = "Something"
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: What's wrong with a friedly greeting ;) And yes, the 'i'.. I always forget to uppercase them. But thanks for the edit!

Comment: Though you meant only to be polite with your greeting, since Stack Overflow isn't a message board we prefer that questions just contain the question. It saves space, avoids bloat, and keeps the OCD happy. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I'll keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a custom library folder for common classes

```
application/
    library/    < for common classes
```

If you are using some classes not only in one controller but at many places in your project this is a good approach.

You just have  to add this new `application/library/` folder to your `include path` in your boostrap file.

Another approach is to have an action helper. But as I described the common classes folder should be a good solution. However I found some interesting resources, most of them are about cross module coding but they might help you anyway http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Code-re-use-across-modules-td668554.html and [How to Use Same Models in Different Modules in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259456/how-to-use-same-models-in-different-modules-in-zend-framework)

---

Let me describe another approach

```
class BasicController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public static $variable = '';

    public function init()
    {
        self::$variable = 'assign value';
    }
}

class HomeController extends BasicController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $bioVar = parrent::$variable;
    }
}
```

This is better than simply extending controllers because they represent actions and each action has a corresponding view script. However all your classes should be registered in autoloader.

Comment: I allready have quite the extensive library, but the stuff that is in the controller class I wouldn't consider as something to put in the library - I understand your idea. But i see the library as a toolbox that I can reuse on another project, and controllers are classes that handles flow, input, model handling and preps data for the view-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have instantiate the class from Zend Autoloader, the error should go away.

You should have the following code in your bootstrap.php file:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
       'namespace' => '',
       'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules',
    ));
    return $autoloader;
}
```

In general, the controllers are loaded via Zend_Controller_Dispatcher, you should use Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader to instantiate the class from other controllers.

Comment: Actually I decided that Extending the Order module to my Mobile module, could potentially be a very bad idea, as it's a different platform. So just went with a 'blank' module, and copied the bits i needed. But the idea of extending modules, could be a quite good idea for let's say an article/news module.

Comment: @Philiplip: 
Yes I agree. But for cases like mobile platform, you can re-use the code  in the form of an API.

You can make your module work as an API and normal flow with the help of view-action helper called "Context Switch" means you can switch the view to HTML, JSON or XML. That way, you don't have to copy your code to a different module for mobile, but have same code and switch the context based on the request. [http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch]

Comment: So, let's say you want to access "comments" action in "xml" format from API, then you should do.. for ex:  `if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "api.example.com") {$this->_helper->contextSwitch()->addActionContext('comments', array('xml', 'json'))->initContext();}`